# angular @ngrx - How should I design the state when i have multiple views showing the same data

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an App with several pages/areas

One page shows products , the other vendors etc,

When i show a product, i also have its price category, like "seat in" ,"TA" etc

I define these price categories on a different page (where i will have the options to add and remove price categories)

My main/root state should have

```
{
   products:Product[],
   priceCategories:PriceCategory[],
   ....
}
```

I want that the page that handles adding/removing of price categories to be lazy loaded.

I want that this last page would have its own state (for example for keeping the selected item)

But, i want that when adding/removing price category , it will effect the main state

Maybe something like this:

```
{
       products:Product[],
       priceCategories:PriceCategory[], -- i need this on multiple pages
       priceCategoriesPage:{
           selectedItemIndex:number,
           otherPageSpesificProp:number   
       }
}
```

Am I going the right path?

on what Effects class should i handle adding/removing item?

On the app.effects.ts or in the price-categories.effects.ts?

Thanks

Comment: Hey , did you find a solution  ?

Comment: Hi, did not do it yet but i think i will put all the state on the root state and not in lazy loaded modules state. Sometimes i need to set the selected item from one view to another view, i can't understand how to do it without the state being on the root

Comment: Currently what i did what having the PriceCategory[] list on the main state and the selectedRowIndex in the lazy module state. I know this is bad but could not find a better way now